# Scandit sdk does not scan specified Hotspot area in iphone6

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I have integrated scandit sdk in my app. It scans with specified Hotspot area in all android devices and iphone 5s. But it is not scanning on the specified Hotspot area in iphone6 and its successors.

Comment: There should not be any differences between different iOS phones. Can you please provide the exact scan settings that you are using?